# How to access 2 level nDarray using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I ran the below code and I have 2 queries from that -

```
import pandas as pd
myNDarray =[[1,2,3,['x1','x2']],['a','b','c']]
myarray = pd.Series(myNDarray)
myarray
# myarray[0][1][1]
```

1) How the output is below for index 1 :- 
0    [1, 2, 3, [x1, x2]]
1              [a, b, c]
dtype: object

Why is it not like below?
0    [1, 2, 3, [x1, x2]]
1    [a, b, c]
dtype: object

2) When I uncomment the commented line in the code, it turns out to be below code and gave the below issue -

```
import pandas as pd
myNDarray =[[1,2,3,['x1','x2']],['a','b','c']]
myarray = pd.Series(myNDarray)
myarray
myarray[0][1][1]
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 myarray = pd.Series(myNDarray)
      4 myarray
----> 5 myarray[0][1][1]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Why does it give this error? What is the way to access 'x1' element? Please suggest

I tried this code but it did not work.

I want to access the element with value 'x1'

Comment: your indexing is wrong, `x1` is at `myarray[0][3][0]`

Comment: Thank you @ChrisA . It resolved the issue